# Rails Fixtures without Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to create fixtures without a name? Something like:

> --:
>     name: ...
>     description: ...
>
> --:
>     name: ...
>     description: ...

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: @Miquel I have a large data set without any relationships that I need to use for testing. The data set is being extracted from an XML file and I wanted to do as little work as possible to import it. I know that CSV fixtures support non-named entries, and was just curious if YML has a syntax for supporting it. Furthermore, the data is often non-unique and as such, the best I could do for naming it is a random name (which seems like it is defeating the purpose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't you'll have to use a random name. If you take a look at the [insert_fixtures function](http://apidock.com/rails/Fixtures/insert_fixtures) you'll notice that it depends on a fixture label to do it's work. To see this in action, try creating a sample yml file like this:

```
# sample.yml
a:
  value: 'hi'
a:
  value: 'world'
```

And then loading it in Ruby:

```
YAML.load(File.open('sample.yml').read)
```

You'll get this result:

```
{"a"=>{"value"=>"world"}}
```

That's because of the way YAML loads hashes. The keys are distinct, so you need to have unique keys in your yaml files. That's why the fixtures code depends on a unique label.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the answer!

Answer (score -1):

In the end, your fixtures will be added to your test database anyway, creating models and calling `save`, so why spending time converting the XML to YAML or CSV when you can just parse your XML and seed your database?

This way you'll have less work to do when adding new data to your tests or extending the scope of your testing.